# Build with clang for older ubuntu releases

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, clang, dynamic-linking

So the problem started as I lately updated my Ubuntu Vivid (15.04). Now `clang-3.5` depends on `libstdc++-4.9` (instead of previous version of `4.8`) and my compiled programs fail to run on Trusty (14.04):

```
./my_app: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./my_app)
```

Both on the development machine and target machine `g++` and `gcc` version `4.8.4` is installed. But the new clang version adds a version dependency required from `libstdc++6` on `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` which only exists on the development and not the target machine.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**:

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997068/2295964) suggesting to statically link to `libstdc++` and there is good read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13636513/2295964) investigating pros and cons of such approach. But are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score -1):

In case your problem has not been solved yet, I can suggest two options aside from static linking:

1. Bundle all libraries required with your apps and set up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `rpath` for your binaries.
2. If you're developing server-side apps, shipping those as Docker images inherited from Ubuntu Vivid may also be an option.